# Text Gradient with animation not working in IE

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, gradient

I want to display a text with animated gradient .. I  found many code but none of them work in IE 11.

Here is the code which works in chrome..but not in IE

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
  margin:0;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
  
  <!-- Background -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#222" width="100%" height="100%" />
  
  <!-- Text using the #pattern in defs as the fill -->
  <text x="50%" text-anchor="middle" y="50%" dy="0.4em" fill="url(#pattern)" font-family="sonos-logoregular" font-size="50vh">SONOS</text>
  
  <defs>  
    <!-- Da gradient -->
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#33235b;"/>
      <stop offset="25%" style="stop-color:#D62229;"/>
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:#E97639;"/>
      <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:#792042;"/>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#33235b;"/>
    </linearGradient>
    
    <!-- Stitch 2 gradients together for seamless animation  -->
    <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="300%" height="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="150%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeType="XML"
                 attributeName="x"
                 from="0" to="150%"
                 dur="7s"
                 repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </rect>
      <rect x="-150%" y="0" width="150%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeType="XML"
                 attributeName="x"
                 from="-150%" to="0"
                 dur="7s"
                 repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </rect>
    </pattern>

    <!-- Pull in font -->
    <!-- Copied from: http://static.sonos.com/v1/fonts/logo/sonos-logo-regular-webfont.svg -->
    <font horiz-adv-x="1024" >
      <font-face font-family="sonos-logoregular" units-per-em="2048" ascent="1920" descent="-128" />
      <missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="500" />
      <glyph unicode="&#xd;" horiz-adv-x="682" />
      <glyph unicode=" " />
      <glyph unicode="N" horiz-adv-x="812" d="M0 412h150v636l662 -664v1000h-148v-640l-664 664v-996z" />
      <glyph unicode="O" horiz-adv-x="1946" d="M470 896q0 210 150 364q148 148 362 148t362 -148q150 -154 150 -364q0 -212 -150 -362t-362 -150t-362 150t-150 362zM620 896q0 -152 106 -258q104 -108 256 -108q154 0 256 108q108 108 108 258q0 148 -108 260q-104 108 -256 108q-148 0 -256 -108 q-106 -110 -106 -260z" />
      <glyph unicode="S" horiz-adv-x="674" d="M0 1124q0 -58 26 -110q28 -52 80 -90q32 -26 86 -52q68 -30 124 -46q124 -40 174 -84q34 -30 34 -74q0 -52 -48 -92q-56 -42 -138 -42q-62 0 -122 26q-38 16 -72 40l-118 -80q0 -4 24 -24q24 -24 60 -46q108 -66 228 -66q70 0 132 22q66 24 108 62q44 38 72 92 q24 54 24 110q0 54 -26 110q-28 52 -78 90q-34 28 -88 52q-38 18 -122 46q-122 36 -174 82q-36 32 -36 74q0 54 50 92q54 44 138 44q60 0 120 -26q32 -12 72 -40l120 80q-2 0 -24 24q-18 18 -62 46q-104 64 -226 64q-74 0 -132 -20t-110 -62q-48 -44 -70 -92 q-26 -56 -26 -110z" />
      <glyph unicode="&#xa0;" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2000;" horiz-adv-x="704" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2001;" horiz-adv-x="1408" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2002;" horiz-adv-x="704" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2003;" horiz-adv-x="1408" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2004;" horiz-adv-x="469" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2005;" horiz-adv-x="352" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2006;" horiz-adv-x="234" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2007;" horiz-adv-x="234" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2008;" horiz-adv-x="176" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x2009;" horiz-adv-x="281" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x200a;" horiz-adv-x="78" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x202f;" horiz-adv-x="281" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x205f;" horiz-adv-x="352" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x25fc;" horiz-adv-x="1000" d="M0 0z" />
    </font>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

I also found a library for the animation I searched for..But couldnt find how to use it.I think its the wrong way i imported..

https://sarcadass.github.io/granim.js/examples.html
Gradients with an image mask
[image]

Is there any way to do this using css,svg,javascript or any jquery plugin?

Comment: Add this to your solution: https://leunen.me/fakesmile/

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks..i downloaded it..but cant sort out how to use it in my code..Could you pls show me a sample

Comment: Read the [FAQ](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/faq.html#dev)

Comment: @RobertLongson i read it and gave the script line..but did not work